# PHP compare a GET value with an INT from a table

Tags: php, get, int, compare

This code in PHP always returns false.

I think it's a matter of how I compare values:

```
if (isset($_GET['materia']) and $_GET['materia']==$row['id_materia']){
            echo'<option selected="selected" value="http://www.gonzalohll.com/pedidos.php?curso=1&?materia='.$row['id_materia'] .'">'. $row['materia'] .'</option>';}

            else {
            echo'<option value="http://www.gonzalohll.com/pedidos.php?curso=1&?materia='.$row['id_materia'] .'">'. $row['materia'] .'</option>';}
            }

            echo '</select>';
```

Any help on the subject is much apreciated.

Comment: That doesn't look like the completed code section. Where does $row['id_materia'] come from? Also I assume you haven't var_dump()ed out the values in $_GET['materia'] and $row['id_materia'], do that and tell us what you get.

Comment: I'm embarrased to say that my mistake was on how i used the GET method to send variables. That's it.

Thanks Andrew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the values for the variables that you are using, for see whats happening in your "if" statements.

For example, try this:

```
$id_materia = $row['id_materia'];

if (empty($id_materia)){
    echo 'Incorrect value for id_materia';
} else {
    echo 'id_materia: ' . $id_materia;
}

if (isset($_GET['materia'])){
    echo ". Value for materia (GET): " . $_GET['materia'];
} else {
    echo ". Materia (GET) not exists";
}

echo '<select>';

if (isset($_GET['materia']) && $_GET['materia'] == $row['id_materia']){
     echo'<option selected="selected" value="http://www.gonzalohll.com/pedidos.php?curso=1&?materia='.$row['id_materia'] .'">'. $row['materia'] .'</option>';}
else {
     echo'<option value="http://www.gonzalohll.com/pedidos.php?curso=1&?materia='.$row['id_materia'] .'">'. $row['materia'] .'</option>';}
}

echo '</select>';
```

Comment: I'm embarrased to say that my mistake was on how i used the GET method to send variables. That's it. 

Thanks Allan.